# How to change the files in particualr git commits back in history?

Tags: git, commit

A file `hello.world` is added in **commit A**, and modified in **commit B** and **commit C**.

Now I want to add a file to all three commits (could be the same filename with `hello.world`.**removed appended**) and it contains a message explaining that `hello.world` was removed from the history as part of repo cleanup, and ideally state the checksum of the `hello.world` at the given commit.

Is it possible to do so? How do I do it?

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: You might be able to do it with https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html but this sort of thing is totally against the nature of Git. Commits are immutable.

Comment: Did you try googling your quesiton `How to change the files in particualr git commits back in history?`? My first google hit is https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history .

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do so?

Sure - you can edit history, but it's "against the nature of Git" from the comment.

> How do I do it?

Time to learn git rebasing, there are many tutorials available on the net. In short: assuming commit `C` is the newest one, I would like:

- `git rebase -i @^^^^`

  - `edit` the commit `A`
  - exit editor
- create the  file `hello.world.removed`
- edit that file with the message you want it to have
- `git add` the file
- `git commit --amend` the file to commit `A`
- and then continue with `git rebase --continue`
- and then fix any potential merge conflicts.